# PHP - How to retrieve the contents of the HTML tag

Tags: php, html-parsing

How to retrieve the contents of the HTML tag.

```
    $foo = '<p>

aaaaaa                </p>

<p>            
bbbbbb bb 
bbbbbbb  </p>
         <p>            cccccccc 
ccc</p>';
```

I need to get "aaaaaa"

thank you very much

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP/regex: How to get the string value of HTML tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/828870/php-regex-how-to-get-the-string-value-of-html-tag)

Comment: See this awsner using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1364269/3448695

Answer (score 2):

Use a DOMParser

```
echo trim($dom->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0)->nodeValue); //"prints" aaaaaa
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/130803)

Comment: Thank you, I have a problem with white characters :-( Edit my main question. Thank

Comment: I have edited the answer. See the demo. I have used `trim` , so you wont get any whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$content = null ;
if ( preg_match("/<p[^>]*>(.*?)<\\/p>/si", $foo, $match) )
    $content = $match[1];
```

use $match[2] for the second match, etc.